# Swift iOS -How to pop to different SegmentControl Index using a NavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uisegmentedcontrol

```
                                                //Index=0     //contains buttonToSwitchTab to pop to TabOneVC
                           TabZeroNavCntrlr ----TabZeroVC --- TabChangeVC
          //segmntCntrl   /
NavCntlr--ContainerView---
                          \                     //Index=1
                           TabOneNavCntrlr ---- TabOneVC
```

I have a `NavController` that has`ContainerView` connected to it. Inside the containerView there is a `segmentControl`. The containerView has 2 more nav controllers connected to it that each lead to their own child controllers: `TabZeroVC` and `TabOneVC`. Initially the first view shown is `TabZeroVC` (*selectedSegmentIndex = 0*). There is a button inside there that leads to `TabChangeVC` which has a `buttonToSwitchTab` inside of it. Pressing that button I want to `pop` to `TabOneVC`.

I tried this code below by using my *navigation controller* to make the switch but on the line `tabOneVC.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1` I get a crash: *unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*

I put a break point on it and the *containerVC* gets initialized but it's 3 properties `segmentedControl`, `tabZeroVC`, and `tabOneVC` are all coming up as nil. Since `segmentedControl` is *nil* that's where the crash is happening.

```
class TabChangeVC: UIViewController{

@IBAction func buttonToSwitchTab(sender: UIButton){

    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let containerVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContainerViewController") as! ContainerViewController
    containerVC.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1 //crash happens here
    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(containerVC, animated: true)
  }
}
```

ContainerView:

```
class ContainerViewController:  UIViewController{
     @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
     @IBOutlet weak var tabZeroVC: UIView!
     @IBOutlet weak var tabOneVC: UIView!

...
}
```

`TabOneVC` is *selectedSegmentIndex = 1*

**My question is how do I pop to `TabOneVC` from the `TabChangeVC` and more importantly why is the containerVC's segmentedControl coming up as nil?**

Comment: According to me your first you need to pop all the elements in `NavCntrl0` then push to `navCntrl1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the *segmentedControl* is coming up as *nil* but I was able to `pop` to `tabOneVC` by using `NSNotificationCenter`. I created a func named *tabSwitch()* with the segment I wanted to show and then I added a `listener` inside the `viewDidLoad` of the `ContainerViewController`:

```
class ContainerViewController:  UIViewController{
     @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
     @IBOutlet weak var tabZeroVC: UIView!
     @IBOutlet weak var tabOneVC: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(tabSwitch), name: "tabSwitch", object: nil)
  }

func tabSwitch(){

     self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
     self.tabZeroVC.hidden = true
     self.tabOneVC.hidden = false
  }
}
```

Inside the TabChangeVC I added a `notifier` to trigger it and `navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)` to get back to the `root` vc:

```
class TabChangeVC: UIViewController{

@IBAction func buttonToSwitchTab(sender: UIButton){

     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("tabSwitch", object: nil)
     self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil
let tabOneVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabOneNavigationController") //TabOneNavCntrlr identifire      
tabOneVC.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1 
appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = tabOneVC
```

Comment: Thanks for the help family but it didn't work. I get the same crash result here: tabOneVC.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1 it comes up as nil. I put a break point on it and both TabZeroVC and TabOneVC are coming up as nil. Btw you need to put "as! TabOneController" at the end of: let tabOneVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabOneNavigationController") as! TabOneController or it won't let me access the .segmentedControl on the next line